Is the map $x \in X \mapsto \int_\Omega f(x,\cdot) \mathrm{d}\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ continuous?
Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space, $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and $f: X \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ such that: $(i)$ for every $\omega \in \Omega$, $f(\cdot,\omega): X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous (suppose that $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with the usual topology); $(ii)$ for every $x \in X$, $f(x,\cdot): \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and Lebesgue integrable (suppose that $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra).
Is the map $x \in X \mapsto \int_\Omega f(x,\cdot) \mathrm{d}\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ continuous ?
I have seen the following post, but people do not seem to agree:
Integrating continuous function of two variables by one of the variables, do I get continuous function?
Thank you !

The counterexample in the post you linked answers your question. See also my comment of the accepted (though erroneous) answer. So, I vote to close your question as a duplicate.

See also this answer to a similar post (there, $X=\Bbb N\cup{\infty}$).

If there is an integrable  function $g:\Omega\rightarrow[0,\infty$ such that $|f(x,\omega)|\leq g(\omega)$ for all $x$, then dominate convergence gives you what you want.  In general situations, the are many counter examples.

@AnneBauval Thank you very much !

@Mittens So it works in particular if there is $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $x \in X$, $f(x,\cdot) \leq M$ ?

If the measure $\mu$ is finite, sure.

@Mittens Thank you for your help !
